# How to stream and save Facebook public posts with R?

Tags: facebook, r, rcurl, rjson

I'm trying to stream and save public posts through R. I already got the token and made the search. This is what i've done.

> require(RCurl)
>
> require(rjson)
>
> data <- getURL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=multishow&type=post&access_token=my_token")

That's fine, the "data" character found something.
Now, how can I convert this "data" character into a data frame?
And is it possible to stream this search during a specific timeout?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Ok guys, now I can parse the JSON results from Facebook, but I'm still stuck in coverting as data.frame properly and stream to get new posts. Follow code below:

```
library (RCurl)
library (rjson)
library (plyr)

data <- getURL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=my_query&type=post&access_token=my_token, cainfo="cacert.perm")

#JSON parser
parser <- newJSONParser()
parser$addData(data)
fb.data <- parser$getObject()

#JSON to data.frame 
#sometimes it works direct from rjson
df <- data.frame(fromJSON(fb.data))

#sometimes it works only with plyr package
df <- do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(fb.data, as.data.frame))
```

Either way, I get a data.frame with 1 or 2 observations and hundreds of variables. Last search I did, I got my first observaton with 42 variables, second with 13 variables, and so on. Any clue of how can I handle with it?

Comment: Try for example , `library(XML);xmlParse(data)`;

Comment: Thanks @agstudy. I got "Error: XML content does not seem to be XML".
But i tried to parse with rjson and it worked.


/ parser <- newJSONParser() / parser$addData(data) / facebook <- parser$getObject() / print(facebook)

Answer (score 0):

To set the `timeout` you can serach for a timeout option in the curl general options like this

```
 names(getCurlOptionsConstants())[grep('.*timeout*.',names(getCurlOptionsConstants()))]
```

This give me 6 options:

```
"timeout"              "connecttimeout"      
 "dns.cache.timeout"    "ftp.response.timeout" 
 "timeout.ms"           "connecttimeout.ms"
```

I don't know which one you serach , but I guess you can try something like this:

```
getURL(url,.opts = list(timeout = 10))
```

Comment: Thanks @agstudy, but it didn't work.

I need something like filterStream function, from streamR package.
When I do filterStream(file="tweets.json", track="my_query", timeout=3600, oauth=my_oauth), it keeps streaming every tweet with "my_query" for an hour - 3600 seconds.

Comment: @LuizFelipeFreitas looking at the code of `filterStream`:  I get this : `getURL("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json",...,     .opts = list(verbose = FALSE, timeout=timeout))`. Clearly it is the same code as the solution proposed.

Comment: Righ now i'm running filterStream...it has a "Capturing tweets" message, and it ends after 3600 seconds.
With getURL, i set timeout=1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 and it ends in a second.